# Javascript - Howcome .length won't detect the "t"

Tags: javascript, html, css, character-encoding

To summarize, for my program, I want to be able to detect the 't', and prevent the user from adding something with a quantity of '3t', '3t3', or anything of that matter.

In other words, if the quantity starts with a number, but has letters in it, it will still go through and be added, which is what I DON'T WANT.

### Here's the code for where I add things. Is there any approach I should do differently?

```js
function addProduct(){

    var input = document.getElementById("productName").value;
    var input2 = document.getElementById("cost").value;
    var input3 = parseInt(document.getElementById("quantity").value);
    
    var s_input3 = input3.toString();
    var table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];

    if (isNaN(input2) || input2<0) 
    {
      alert("not a number");
      return(-1);
    }

    if (isNaN(input3) || input3<0)
    {
      alert("not a number");
      return(-1);
    }

  // MY ATTEMPT OF DETECTING THE 't'

  for (i = 0; i < s_input3.length; i++)
  {
    console.log(s_input3.length)
    
    if(!(isNaN(s_input3[0])  && isNan(s_input3[i])))
    {
      alert("not a number")
      return(-3)
    }
  }
```

[image: Visual Example of what's happening]

Comment: In other words: You want an input type number ? Or I missed something ?

Comment: If I understand correctly what you want is to allow only numbers. Have you tried using regex? Also are you giving the html input type="number" ?

Comment: Yes, and what do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to go through each of the character in the string. You can just do isNaN() on the input value.

Comment: I tried that, and it still doesn't deal with the '3t' case.

Answer (score 0):

The isNan() function does work on 3t as this code example shows. It might seem initially counter intuitive as a double negative, but the global function tests 'is not a number' so a number is false and a string true. Try code example below.

```
<html>

<body>

<p id="testOutput"></p>

<button onclick="testNumber()">Test is number</button>

<script>
function testNumber() {
  var output = "";
  output= output + isNaN('3t') + ": 3t<br>";
  output = output + isNaN(3) + ": 3<br>";
  document.getElementById("testOutput").innerHTML = output;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Output is:

true: 3t

false: 3

[W3Schools Ref](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isnan.asp#:%7E:text=The%20isNaN()%20function%20determines,from%20the%20Number%20specific%20Number.)

Comment: It says "false" when I type in 3t.

Comment: Take out the || input3<0 from your if statement and try again.